# Dovecot: increase ssl_dh_parameters_length

Tags: ssl, dovecot, encryption

I'm using Dovecot 2.2.21

I set `ssl_dh_parameters_length = 4096`.
Before that, I had set `2048`. After the change I reloaded Dovecot.

Since then, SSL doesn't work any more and I get these logs in`/var/log/dovecot.err`:

```
Jan 10 17:03:41 mail dovecot: ssl-params: Fatal: Timeout while waiting for /var/db/dovecot/ssl-parameters.dat generation to complete
```

Is there a way to increase the timeout or to increase the DH Params in background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error actually means it was unable to open the file it wants to save into. Seems a bit poorly worded. There is no timeout for taking too long to actually generate the params, only for it getting the lock for the file it wants to write into. See the code at http://hg.dovecot.org/dovecot-2.2/file/42b5cde2d560/src/ssl-params/ssl-params.c and specifically:

```
/* If multiple dovecot instances are running, only one of them needs
   to regenerate this file. */
ret = file_wait_lock(fd, temp_path, F_WRLCK,
             FILE_LOCK_METHOD_FCNTL,
             SSL_BUILD_PARAM_TIMEOUT_SECS, &lock);
if (ret < 0)
    i_fatal("file_try_lock(%s) failed: %m", temp_path);
if (ret == 0) {
    /* someone else is writing this */
    i_fatal("Timeout while waiting for %s generation to complete",
        path);
}
```

This could mean there's another instance running, or a temp file didn't clean up properly, or whatever. Try shutting down all dovecot instances, removing the file it was trying to open and, if it's there, the .tmp version of the same, and then start dovecot again. Hopefully that will see you through.

Comment: Thanks! I still had several `ssl-params`processes running from my previous tests. I stopped dovecot, quit the processes, deleted the `/var/db/dovecot/ssl-parameters.dat` and `/var/db/dovecot/ssl-parameters.dat.tmp` and restarted dovecot. After a while everything worked again.